# Какой уровень доступа получат переменные?

Tags: java

объясните записи

1:

```
Object obj = new Object() {
    Integer id = 10;
    String name = "name";
};
```

2:

```
Object obj = new Object() {
    {
        Integer id = 10;
        String name = "name";
    }
};
```

в чем разница между этими записями?
в какую область видимости попадут переменные и какие модификаторы доступа они получат?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Вы создаёте экземпляр анонимного класса, который является наследником класса `Object` с двумя новыми полями. Так как эти поля объявлены без модификаторов доступа, то они получат модификаторы доступа по умолчанию. Можно будет обращаться к этим полям как `obj.id` и `obj.name`.
2. Вы создаёте экземпляр анонимного класса, который является наследником класса `Object`. Новых полей у этого класса нет, но есть так называемый [`Instance initialization block`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). Это такой блок, который будет выполнен при каждом создании экземпляра класса. Можно считать, что код внутри этого блока будет скопирован в начало каждого конструктора. Таким образом, переменные, объявленные внутри этого блока, являются обычными локальными переменными, и исчезнут после выхода из блока.